# How to use lightbox options?

Tags: javascript, lightbox, lightbox2

How I can to use lightbox 2 options? How to include in document? It does not work as specified on the site  http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#options

```
<script>
    lightbox.option({
      'resizeDuration': 200,
      'wrapAround': true
    })
</script>


<a class="example-image-link" data-lightbox="example-set" href="pic.png">
  <img style="width: 100%" src="pic.png">
</a>
```

How do you set the lightbox options?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Please create a minimal example with your code to let us see what could've went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are including both the lightbox.js **AND** lightbox.css stylesheet.

You will also need jQuery 1.7 or greater (as stated in step 4 of the [Getting Started section of the Lightbox website](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started)). You should include the jQuery script before the lightbox script.

This setup worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.7.1/css/lightbox.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.7.1/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a class="example-image-link" data-lightbox="example-set" href="pic.png">
  <img style="width: 100%" src="pic.png">
</a>

<script>
lightbox.option({
  'resizeDuration': 200,
  'wrapAround': true
  })
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No it doesn't. Not with that version of Lightbox. Here's a jsbin with exactly your code: http://jsbin.com/vazekij/edit?html,output